# How to find installation path in virtual environment?

Tags: python, cuda, anaconda, virtualenv

I created virtual environment using anaconda python. I installed cuda toolkit in the created environment. Now I have to give path of cuda installation in makefile. Default path /usr/local/cuda/include/ doesn't exist. How can I find the right path  of cuda ?

I have to make changes in make file given below

```
COMMON+= -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/
CFLAGS+= -DGPU
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand
```

The command `which nvcc` gives `/usr/bin/nvcc`

`locate cuda | grep /cuda$` gives

```
/home/tan/.conda/envs/tensorflow_env/include/opencv2/core/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/envs/tensorflow_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/envs/tensorflow_gpu/include/opencv2/core/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/local_config_cuda/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/local_config_cuda/cuda/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/pkgs/libopencv-3.4.2-hb342d67_1/include/opencv2/core/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/pkgs/numba-0.42.0-py36h962f231_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/pkgs/opencv3-3.1.0-py36_0/include/opencv2/core/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.10.0-mkl_py36h3c3e929_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/local_config_cuda/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.10.0-mkl_py36h3c3e929_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/local_config_cuda/cuda/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.10.0-mkl_py36h3c3e929_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.12.0-gpu_py36had579c0_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/local_config_cuda/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.12.0-gpu_py36had579c0_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/local_config_cuda/cuda/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.12.0-gpu_py36had579c0_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.12.0-mkl_py36h3c3e929_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/local_config_cuda/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.12.0-mkl_py36h3c3e929_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/external/local_config_cuda/cuda/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.12.0-mkl_py36h3c3e929_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.3.0-py27h0dbb4d0_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda
/home/tan/.conda/pkgs/tensorflow-base-1.3.0-py36h5293eaa_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda
/home/tan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/cuda
/home/tan/anaconda3/pkgs/numba-0.38.0-py36h637b7d7_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/build/modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/perf/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/build_dnn/modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/perf/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/build_gpu/modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/perf/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/core/perf/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/core/src/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/cudaarithm/src/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/cudabgsegm/src/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/cudacodec/src/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/cudafeatures2d/src/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/cudafilters/src/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/cudaimgproc/src/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/cudalegacy/src/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/cudaobjdetect/src/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/cudaoptflow/src/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/cudastereo/src/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/cudawarping/src/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/photo/src/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/stitching/src/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/superres/src/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv-3.4.1/modules/videostab/src/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv_contrib-3.4.1/modules/hfs/src/cuda
/home/tan/opencv3/opencv_contrib-3.4.1/modules/xfeatures2d/src/cuda
/usr/include/flann/util/cuda
```

Answer (score 2):

Full CUDA installation via runfile for ubuntu is 2.4 GB, while anaconda only ~370 MB. The latter contains all dependencies required to run libraries that depend on it, e.g. PyTorch or Tensorflow. It's not a full installation and most likely does not have what you're looking for.

You need a full development package which can be found on [Nvidia website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple full installations of CUDA on your machine. It is my understanding that CUDA is backwards compatible, so you only need one.

However, compiling using a newer version of CUDA might link you incompatible newer libraries of other packages.

If you do need to install multiple versions of CUDA you need to add links to .bashrc and what not. Here is a website with instructions

https://medium.com/@peterjussi/multicuda-multiple-versions-of-cuda-on-one-machine-4b6ccda6faae

tl;dr  run this command.

> sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64